# Doctrine Named Queries: Specifing limit on query call

Tags: php, doctrine, dql, named-query

Let's imagine something like this:

```
class MyTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
    public function construct()
    {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('MyTable t')
                                     ->orderBy('t.creationDate DESC')
                                     ->limit(5);
        $this->addNamedQuery('top5', $q);
    }
}
```

Later I can do something like this:

```
$top5 = Doctrine::getTable('MyTable')->find('top5');
```

Is there any way I can set the limit when using the named query, and not when defining it? I'd would really love to do something like:

```
$top5 = Doctrine::getTable('MyTable')->find('topX', 5);
```

or

```
$top5 = Doctrine::getTable('MyTable')->find('topX', array('limit' => 5));
```

Thx in advance! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from writing your own method or function that clones the named unlimited query, sets a limit on the clone and then returns results.

Answer (score 1):

I think the shortest way can be:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()->select()->from('MyTable')->limit(5)->execute();
```